# this dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022 error is killing me exclamation point goes here

Tags: android, command, android-virtual-device, dyld

I have a 2.2 mac Core 2 Duo - I think they call my mac Santa Rosa or something.

I've spent the last three months on App Inventor - after realizing I can't use admob or Airpush - I decided to start learning java.

I've been watching a set of 200 tutorials by thenewboston and it is great!

Only problem is, i can't start the emulator. I think it has something to do with the fact when it asks me how much space the sdcard should hold - when i try to prEss enter - it won't let me continue..

```
[2013-01-22 09:46:46 - SDK Manager] dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022
[2013-01-22 09:46:46 - SDK Manager] Failed to create the SD card.     
[2013-01-22 09:46:46 - SDK Manager] Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder.
```

ok so, of Course i googled it.

here's what i found.

https://plus.google.com/110164642453700713590/posts/StCNjEywBPU

and it gave me this...

Device-873EF9:~ Tahj182$ sudo xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine android-sdk-macosx/option -r not recognized

```
   usage: xattr [-l] file [file ...]
   xattr -p [-l] attr_name file [file ...]
   xattr -w attr_name attr_value file [file ...]
   xattr -d attr_name file [file ...]
```

The first form lists the names of all xattrs on the given file(s).
The second form (-p) prints the value of the xattr attr_name.
The third form (-w) sets the value of the xattr attr_name to attr_value.
The fourth form (-d) deletes the xattr attr_name.

options:
  -h: print this help
  -l: print long format (attr_name: attr_value)
Device-873EF9:~ Tahj182$

sooooo... i tried this..

http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/26/create-and-use-emulated-sd-card/

and i get this..

Device-873EF9:~ Tahj182$ /Users/Tahj182/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64\ 2/sdk/tools/mksdcard ; exit;
dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022
Trace/BPT trap
logout

[Process completed]

ok , so in my eclispse.. my avd manager wont start

I could keep going, showing how my googled solutions got me no where..

can you help me please guys!

:-)

Comment: How much space are you specifying for the SD Card?   Please show *exactly* what you are typing in.

Comment: what amount of space should i specify. ive tried 9, 256, 100 and nothing is working. thanks simon for looking over my question and evn taking the time to answer it. or question it rather. also http://i742.photobucket.com/albums/xx69/macfan182/Picture1.png  if you look at that picture. it shows it hasnt created the .java file i think i have a bad version of java. tried downloading the most recent version but upon installing the software. it doesnt start to intall

Comment: i just tried a lot of other numbers.. still getting this error::::            [2013-01-22 12:57:36 - SDK Manager] dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022
[2013-01-22 12:57:36 - SDK Manager] Failed to create the SD card.
[2013-01-22 12:57:36 - SDK Manager] Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder.

Comment: @simon http://i742.photobucket.com/albums/xx69/macfan182/Picture2.png i tried another IDE it .. look at the error message

Comment: i think me running 10.5.8 has something to do with it

Answer (score 0):

I think, or at this point, I'm more than sure it has something to do with the fact that I'm running 10.5.8 (Leopard).

I downloaded Eclipse Classic because of this advice.

https://www.buzztouch.com/files/howtos/buzztouch_For_Android-A_Users_Guide.pdf

Eclipse Classic shows Java EE but I can't see Android in the preferences menu.

still with a dyld error. and also the .jar file seems to have no red x's.

Yet, when I run the bundle, I see Android but can't start the AVD. I still enter a value for the SD Card  and there seems to be A red X on the first and only .jar file of the class I created.

So, I guess my question is answered. But I still don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: FYI, I've also gotten a "unknown required load command 0x80000022" running modern (as of 2012) apps under MacOS 10.5.8.